# Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'id' was called on null. in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, floor

Im trying to display all inserted data every time user insert or update the data, however i encounter this error during the development **'Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'id' was called on null.'** any suggestion will be appreciated.

here is my Code

```
    saveContactData() {
    final database = $FloorContactDatabase.databaseBuilder('Contacts.db').build();
    database.then((onValue) {
      onValue.contactsDao.getMaxTodo().then((isvalue) {
        int id = 1;
        if(onValue != null) {
          print(onValue);
          id = isvalue.id + 1; //MY ERROR IS HERE
        }
          onValue.contactsDao.insertContact(ContactObject(id: id,
              firstname: firstnameController.text,
              lastname: lastnameController.text,
              birthday: int.parse(firstnameController.text.trim()),
              contactnumber: int.parse(contactnumberController.text.trim()),
              profilepicture: Image.file(_image).toString()
          ));


      });
    });
  }
```

This is my repo were i call the id

```
    @entity
class ContactObject {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate: true)
    int id;
    String firstname;
    String lastname;
    int birthday;
    int contactnumber;
    String profilepicture;

    @ignore
    bool isSelect = false;
    ContactObject ({this.id , this.firstname, this.lastname, this.birthday, this.contactnumber, this.profilepicture});//need to change if needed

    @override
    String toString(){
      return 'ContactObject{id: $id, firstname: $firstname, lastname: $lastname, birthday: $birthday, contactnumber: $contactnumber, profilepicture: $profilepicture}';
    }

    static ContactObject formMap(Map<String, dynamic> extend) {
        if(extend == null) return null;
          ContactObject contacts = ContactObject();
          contacts.id = extend['id'];
          contacts.firstname = extend['firstname'];
          contacts.lastname = extend['lastname'];
          contacts.birthday = extend['birthday'];
          contacts.contactnumber = extend['contactnumber'];
          contacts.profilepicture = extend['profilepicture'];
          return contacts;
    }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap(){
      return{
        "id": id,
        "firstname": firstname,
        "lastname": lastname,
        "birthday": birthday,
        "contactnumber": contactnumber,
        "profilepicture" : profilepicture
      };
  }

}
```

Here is my query in database

```
`@override
  Future<ContactObject> getMaxTodo() {
    return _queryAdapter.query('SELECT * FROM ContactObject order by id desc limit 1',
        mapper: _todoMapper);
  }
`
```

Comment: what  `isvalue` displayed?

Comment: hi @JohnJoe no sir my error is the id right after isvalue.

Comment: try print out isValue and see. Perhaps it is null?

Comment: @ShanMichaelReyes  just do debug your code its solve your problem easily :)

Comment: @JohnJoe yes null sir

Comment: hi @ParthPitroda what do you mean just debug sir ?

Comment: @ShanMichaelReyes using debug u can find out your mistake in code

Comment: so check why it returning null.

Comment: How do you get ```isvalue``` the problem lies with it having no value. Could you please add code for ```getMaxTodo()```?

Comment: hi @Crazzygamerr please see my edited question for your request thanks for the response

Comment: Thx for the code. I think you should check if either onValue or isValue is returning null, coz that's the only way you can get the error. Try printing some values to check where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Just use  dart null avoid operator

```
if(onValue != null) {
    print(onValue);
    id = isvalue?.id??0 + 1; 
}
```

in the code above, `isvalue` is `null` then `id` initially falls back to the `0`, finally resulting in `1`

Comment: hi john the error is gone but there is no data that display in Listview Thanks for the response